# "No authentication header supplied." error while running cypher from neo4j browser

Tags: neo4j

I found similar questions online but in the context of java code. I am facing this error while running cypher from the neo4j browser. I have to run the same cypher several time, until accidently it gets executed. Rarely query runs in 4-5 attempts, in most cases I have to try 20+ times. This is how it looks in the browser:

[image]

The error continues after running `:server connect` too. How do I fix this once forever. I am fed up rerunning cypher...

**Added**: I am using Neo4j CE 3.0.4. Can it be due the fact that I might be using databases created in old versions?

Comment: closing and opening browser window seems to do the trick. Why is this so?

Comment: Which internet browser are you using?

Comment: I was in Chrome Incognito